# ActiveXObject is not defined for all browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, activexobject

> Trying to read information from card using a smartcard reader to implement it on the web

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function comEventOccured(myform) {
        try {
            var obj = new ActiveXObject("mykadproweb.mykadproweb.jpn");
            var strRet = obj.BeginJPN("FT SCR2000 0");
            if (strRet == "0") {
                document.forms[0].txtIDNum.value = obj.getIDNum();
                document.forms[0].txtBirthDate.value = obj.getBirthDate();
                document.forms[0].txtKPTName.value = obj.getKPTName();
                document.forms[0].txtOldIDNum.value = obj.getOldIDNum();
                document.forms[0].txtReligion.value = obj.getReligion();
                document.forms[0].txtGender.value = obj.getGender();
                document.forms[0].txtRace.value = obj.getRace();
                document.forms[0].txtAddress1.value = obj.getAddress();
                strRet=obj.getPhoto("c:\\myphotov1.jpg");
                //load image
                var file_location = document.getElementById('show_pic');
                file_location.innerHTML='<img src="c:\\myphotov1.jpg" width="150px" height="200px"></img>';

                obj.EndJPN();
            }
            else {
                alert("mykadproweb message: " + strRet);
            }
        } catch (e) {
                alert("mykadpro: You dont have MYKAD SDK or FT SCR2000 reader." + e.message);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Are there any way that I'm able to read the information from the local directory?

Comment: ActiveX is a proprietary Microsoft thing. Other browsers (not to mention other operating systems) don't support it.

Comment: Not even Microsoft supports it anymore, in Edge.

Comment: @Pointy Any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not, for security reasons.